# How to make my own professional book step-by-step (there is a course or a book that I didn't find?)

Tags: books, tutorials

Sorry if this question is not doubts about `LaTeX` per se, but more a question for a guide to making my own book. There is a book or a course or a tutorial available specifically about making my own book step-by-step? Share your knowledge about this topic, please. I want to make my books professionally. That's all. Thank you everyone in advance!

Comment: Depending on the type of book, you could also look into ebook software in general. If it's just text and pictures then this is maybe easier depending on your educational background.

Comment: Have you considered other software that may use an easier to write format on the frontend and then mangle that into LaTeX and subsequently a PDF, for example? Pandoc and mdbook come to mind. Reading [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) by NoStarch gave me the feeling that the latter is fairly powerful. Nothing against LaTeX, but I found there are lots of things in my domain of expertise (software development) where characters like `_` in identifiers frequently break the paradigm LaTeX advertises, because some characters are harder to pass to commands/macros.

Comment: Related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316933/what-to-decide-before-writing-a-math-book

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answer in order to close the question.

Comment: Sorry, everyone, @Dr.ManuelKuehner, this is my first question on StackExchange!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest reading Robert Bringhurst's *The Elements of Typographic Style* which is the best book I have come across on the subject. Then there is my *A Few Notes on Book Design* (`> texdoc memdesign`) based on my experience in creating books and other publications. After that use the `memoir` class (`> texdoc memoir`) which provides many means of creating professional books. (Warning: I'm the originator of `memoir`.)

Good luck in your endeavours.

Comment: Wow, I have a lot of materials to read right now, my head is spinning. But thank you for your precious time!

Answer (score 9):

- First of all, this is a very big time effort in my opinion. Let's say 200+ h.
- There is the so-called `KOMA-Script` bundle that is similar to the `memoir` class.
- It comes with a extensive documentation (500+ pages), see https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script ([direct link](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) to the PDF file).
- The `KOMA-Script` bundle gives you a lot of tools. If you are serious about "writing a professional book" than this is at least one option that you should consider.
- You can also read a book of a "famous" author, for example [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0073FTN5I](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0073FTN5I) (by [Stefan Kottwitz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/213/)).
- Other than that, it's always good to have a look at [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11).