# Latex upgrade hell - Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: errors, luatex, ubuntu

So I have just made an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04, meaning TexLive has upgraded from the 2013 to the 2015 version, and TexMaker from 4.1-1 to 4.4.1-1.1.

None of my tex scripts now work properly, so I am wondering if I am missing something big to have into account when upgrading. I use LuaLateX + View PDF to compile them.

- The most obvious problem I am experiencing is with TexMaker PDF viewer, which shows a much much wider pdf (like double the width), though the pdf (in the simplest of cases) is compiled correctly.

Once I try more complicated scripts, I find several problems I have no idea how to debug...

Some of them are the following:

> fontspec error: "font-not-found"! The font "DroidArabicNaskh" cannot
>   be found.

I thought this font came free with Linux, but there's nowhere to be found now...

> ! Undefined control sequence. \texthebrew #1->\bgroup \luatextextdir
>   TRT\hebrewfont #1\egroup l.622 \end{frame}

This happens when I use the following to write a little sample text in hebrew, which worked perfectly before...

```
\newfontfamily{\hebrewfont}{Linux Libertine O} 
\newcommand{\texthebrew}[1]{%
    \bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\hebrewfont #1\egroup%
}
```

!

> Illegal parameter number in definition of \blx@defformat@d. to be
>   read again 3

I don't know what this means, but comes from these lines in a cls file:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \small\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray}%
  \ifblank{#3}{}{#3\space}#1%
  \ifthenelse{\value{listcount}<\value{liststop}}
    {\addcomma\space}
    {}%
}
```

> ! Use of \sortlist doesn't match its definition. l.21 \sortlist{
>   entry}{chronological}

I don't understand what this means or where it comes from

> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. l.21 \sortlist{entry}
>   {chronological}

Again, I don't know what this sortlist thing is...

> ! Undefined control sequence. \entry ...ata@\the \c@refsection
>   @\blx@slist@name @\abx@field@entrykey }\csu...
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.  ...fter \ifstrequal
>   \expandafter {\blx@slist@type }{entry} {\listcsxadd {blx...

My scripts show a whole lot of undefined control sequence errors, that before the upgrade didn't show...

> Package biblatex Warning: File 'mybib.bbl' is wrong format
>   version - expected 2.6.

Has the way of introducing bibliography changed??

Many of the errors show in my version of the Friggeri CV template, but none of these errors showed before the upgrade...

So am I missing something important here? Otherwise I will make a question for each different problem I am finding and see... Many thanks!

Comment: Is the last sentence a threat ? :) On a more serious note, I have confirmed a few times that this guide goes through without any problems on 16.04 http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373

Comment: I tend to stick to the Ubuntu repository when I can, would that be possible in this case? Or has texlive been reported to not work properly for 16.04?

Comment: There were some problems with the Biber/`biblatex` versions in the repositories some weeks ago. If you want to be able to update your packages properly from CTAN you should go for the "vanilla" version. Case in point: You'll find that a current TeX live would be 2016 and not 2015. Some of the errors you mention look like they could be solved by recompiling from scratch (delete the temporary `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ... files). Another is [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864). Maybe you can find a newer version of the friggery template.

Comment: luatex was *very* beta in TL2013. No one ever promised that it wouldn't change (and it did change a lot, even from TL15 to TL16). So it is quite possible that you will have to adapt your document. I would actually recommend to get TL16 directly. Regarding the biblatex problem: Delete your auxiliary files (bbl and bcf) and recompile.

Comment: Alright removing files and recompiling got rid of many errors indeed, so I'm going to see if I make this whole thing work with repository packages (TL2015). So far I only have problems with Texmaker (but I can use some other editor), and with my Friggeri-style CV (which I would need to adapt), plus a little problem with transliteration (this answer to a question I posted doesn't seem to work anymore for arabic and hebrew http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250288/chinese-russian-and-english-and-arabic-and-thai-if-possible-in-lualatex)...

Comment: So I guess I will ask 3 independent questions to these better defined problems, now that I'm not freaking out that much...

Comment: Related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/247524/do-i-risk-breaking-documents-by-updating-my-tex-distribution