# auto-pst-pdf and pdfpages became incompatible?

Tags: pdfpages, compilation-error, auto-pst-pdf

As I'm obviously ignorant with regard to some [well-intended advices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247526/18258), I ran into a compilation error after updating my MiKTeX distribution after two or three months. I was able to track the error down to the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example-image-a.pdf}

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compiling using `pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex` will show compilation errors during the `auto-pst-pdf` stage. `mwe-autopp.log` reads somewhat like:

```
[...]
File: example-image-b.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<example-image-b.eps>
Preview: Tightpage -39321600 -39321600 39321600 39321600
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth 
                              -\@m \p@ 
l.13    \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
                                           
Sorry, but I'm not programmed to handle this case;
I'll just pretend that you didn't ask for it.
If you're in the wrong mode, you might be able to
return to the right one by typing `I}' or `I$' or `I\par'.

! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.13    \includegraphics{example-image-b.eps}
[...]
```

Compilation will run fine when either the `\includepdf` line or the `figure` environment are commented out, respectively. Could you please advice me on how to fix this one...? Thanks a lot!

/edit
In response to comments by @Marijn and @Ulrike Fischer:

You are right, my MNWE was not chosen very cleverly! As a matter of fact, I also need the `chemnum` package in my real-world example to replace strings within the eps file. This method does need the `auto-pst-pdf` package and the `--shell-escape` option for pdflatex as far as I know. Let me slightly expand the example from above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}

\includepdf{example-image-a.pdf}

\begin{figure}
    \replacecmpd[tag=benzene]{benzene}
    \includegraphics{benzene.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I've put the contents of `benzene.eps` to Pastebin: [click](https://pastebin.com/czr3jmNS).

Comment: Remove `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}`, the conversion of eps to pdf is automatic (`shell-escape` is also not needed).

Comment: (note that this wouldn't work with `example-image-b.eps` because that is located in a system folder where a converted pdf cannot be written, but it should work with a normal eps located in the folder of your .tex document)

Comment: while I quite agree that auto-pst-pdf is not needed here, did you update everything? The prevdepth error could indicate older files somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, Marijn and Ulrike Fischer! I think I need `auto-pst-pdf` and `--shell-escape` as my real world example also requires the `chemnum` package. I've updated the initial question to better reflect this situation. I also made sure that MiKTeX is up-to-date both within user and administrator mode.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get any error message with your second example. (My TeX installation might not be the most recent one, but at least chemnum, auto-pst-pdf and pdfpages are up-to-date.)

Comment: @AndreasMatthias - I happen to have a "clean" Windows 10 installation in a virtual machine. After installing MiKTeX basic (and enabling on-the-fly installation of packages), I ran the second example which includes `benzene.eps`. I ran into the same error as described before... Maybe this is related to a package other than `chemnum`, `auto-pst-pdf` and `pdfpages`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

miktex hasn't the newest eso-pic yet, it still use eso-pic 2020/09/27 v2.0i eso-pic.

The problem with this version is that it adds material starting with `\nointerlineskip` in the shipout/before hook, and due to the changes in the shipout routine in LaTeX this gets into the preview code in horizontal mode and harms there.

```
\__hook shipout/before ->\nointerlineskip \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft {\put (0,\Le
nToUnit {\ESO@yoffsetI }){\ESO@HookIIIBG \ESO@HookIBG \ESO@HookIIBG \global \le
t \ESO@HookIIBG \@empty }}\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeftForeground {\put (0,\LenToUni
t {\ESO@yoffsetI }){\ESO@HookIFG \ESO@HookIIFG \ESO@HookIIIFG \global \let \ESO
@HookIIFG \@empty }}\PLS@AtBeginShipout \__hook_next shipout/before 

\nointerlineskip ->\prevdepth -\@m \p@ 
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in horizontal mode.
```

With a newer eso-pic the document compiles for me.

I opened an issue at the miktex issue tracker: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/211.

But be aware that `preview` and `pst-pdf` do some low-level shipout manipulations, and the changes in LaTeX affects them. For example preview is currently not compatible with hyperref: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-auctex/2020-11/msg00000.html.

Comment: My biggest thanks, @Ulrike Fischer! Could you please just briefly comment on where `preview` is invoked? After the MiKTeX repository will be updated to deliver the newer `eso-pic` version: If I get you right, I will also need to apply some code from bug#44578 to fix another incompatibility between `preview` and `hyperref`, right? The way I need to compile my ~ 400 pages document lead to compilation errors every few months when I updated my distribution. It's a pity one can't install 'MiKTeX as of 09/20' to get a functioning distribution... Consistency across machines is also hard to achieve.

Comment: auto-pst-pdf loads pst-pdf which loads preview (and does itself some changes). And if you use hyperref you probably will need the code I suggest in the bug report. (But I don't know if it fix everything, it is quite possible that more problems are lurking somewhere. preview/pst-pdf is quite complicated).

Comment: For reasons unrelated to this question, I reinstalled Windows 10 and set up my MiKTeX. The package manager now lists eso-pic 3.0a as installed. However, when running `pdflatex --shell-escape mwe.tex` on my example which includes `benzene.eps`, I still get errors in `mwe-autopp.log`, see [here](https://pastebin.com/GR9dKXAf) (somewhere around line 465). `hyperref` is not involved in this case, so I guess there is another incompatibility somewhere? Do you have another suggestion, shall I open another question regarding this one? Thank you.