# chemnum, hyperref, and .eps file compatibility

Tags: hyperref, eps, auto-pst-pdf, chemnum

I realize that over the past few years, there have been a lot of issues with getting `preview` to work with `hyperref` (see [here](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=44578) and [Ulrike Fisher's question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/573216/auto-pst-pdf-and-pdfpages-became-incompatible) to reference a couple). When using `chemnum` to auto-number TMP tags in a .eps file (namely from ChemDraw), using the following code was suggested to work:

```
\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\def\@tempa{off}
\ifnum\pdf@shellescape=\@ne\relax
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp
{\pdf@filemoddate{\jobname.tex}}
{\pdf@filemoddate{\jobname-pics.pdf}}
>0 \relax
\def\@tempa{on}
\fi
\fi
\PassOptionsToPackage{\@tempa}{auto-pst-pdf}
\else
\disable@package@load{hyperref}{}
\disable@package@load{bookmark}{}
\fi
\makeatother
```

This works with a MWE, and also with every other package I am using (chemistry related and not). However, due to graduate school dissertation requirements, this fix was not working with the custom `.sty` file. Because this custom `.sty` includes `hyperref`, compilation alsways resulted in the `GPL Ghostscript 10.02.1: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1` error as found in many cases. Whether the aforementioned code was placed in this file or not, `hyperref` was continually causing errors.

My only workaround is to move all `hyperref` options into the preamble of the main `.tex` rather than burying it into a package. Is this bad practice?

A MWE for using the `chemnum` package to automatically number ChemDraw files that have been saved as `.eps` files (with text embedding turned on) is as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{book}% I'm writing a dissertation after all

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\makeatletter
\ifpdf
\def\@tempa{off}
\ifnum\pdf@shellescape=\@ne\relax
\ifnum\pdf@strcmp
{\pdf@filemoddate{\jobname.tex}}
{\pdf@filemoddate{\jobname-pics.pdf}}
>0 \relax
\def\@tempa{on}
\fi
\fi
\PassOptionsToPackage{\@tempa}{auto-pst-pdf}
\else
\disable@package@load{hyperref}{}
%\disable@package@load{bookmark}{}
\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage{chemnum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\replacecmpd[]{1}%tag defaults to TMP and should include a number at the end
\includegraphics{examplefigure.eps}

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I'm not entirely sure if it counts as a MWE without the `examplefigure.eps` file attached, but you can just use your favorite one.

Just for completeness, I use `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex` on TeXStudio with TeXLive2023.

Is this bad practice to bring a package such as `hyperref` from a custom package into the preamble itself? Is there a better option?

Comment: try to remove the hyperref code from the shipout hooks if preview is active as described here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617267/2388

Comment: Using that code to remove `hyperref` code from the shipout hooks seems to fix this issue, until I try to use a .png in a different figure. If there's a `.png` in the document, I get the dreaded `Float(s) lost` error.

Comment: sorry but the hyperref hooks have nothing to do with png or floats. Ask a new question with a proper example